# Парсинг даты из CallLog

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!
Добавляю в своё приложение "Телефонная книга" вывод логов исходящих звонков:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
 cs = ctx.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, callTableColumns, WHERE, new String[] {phoneForCallLog}, ORDER_BY);
 int count = 0;

 if (cs.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
         if (cs.getInt(cs.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)) != 3) {
             String number = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
             String duration = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
             String date = dateFormat.format((cs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
```

Далее при запуске приложения выводится некорректная дата(date). Получаю:
01.01.1970 03:00.
Время на эмуляторе настроено верно. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, с данной проблемой.

Comment: А какое значение возвращает метод `cs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DATE)`?

Comment: @post_zeew Например, по номеру 5 исходящих, cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DATE)) возвращает: 1480057900769, 1479994378164, 1479994368616, 1479988143782, 1477569390846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, Вы хотите использовать метод `format(...)` класса `SimpleDateFormat`, который принимает количество миллисекунд, однако сейчас Вы ему отдаете номер колонки.

Вам необходимо по номеру колонки получить значение, а потом передать это значение методу `foramt(...)`.

Должно быть как-то так:

```
String date = dateFormat.format(cs.getLong(cs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, упустил этот момент. С Вашей правкой всё работает без проблем.